# Unable to confirm Amazon SNS subscription for SES bounces

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am getting the following error when I confirm the subscription on Amazon SNS:

> 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 14f5c18d

*How to resolve this issue?*

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message when I was mistakenly using the Confirm Subscription dialog box to try to force a confirmation, when I really should have just let it confirm through my https page code.  (It wasn't confirming because I had mistyped the page's URI.  Once entered correctly, it confirmed the subscription.)